# Two 3-phase generators in parallel

Tags: power, generator, three-phase

I need to calculate the PF of supply V2, a 3-phase generator that is operating in parallel with another generator (11kV star-connected). Both the generators are equally sharing the mechanical load of 3000kW at 0.8 PF (lagging).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f55788.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I put together the above diagram with the supplied information. If I calculate the total Apparent power (s) as 3750kVA (3000kW/cos(36.87)) and the total current as 246.03A at an angle of -36.87 degrees (3750kVA/sqrt(3)*11kV*0.8).

This gives me an apparent load of 44.71 Ohms at an angle of 36.87 degrees.

How would I go about finding the PF of each of the generators? Is it even possible given the supplied information?

Comment: Look at each generator separately supplying 123.015 A at -36.87 degrees and 11kV at the terminals. Calculate the internal voltage and angle required for the terminal conditions.

Comment: Generator V1 is supplying 150A. The generators are going to be supplying different amounts of current with different PFs because of the two impedance's. The load PF is 0.8 but that doesn't mean the two generators are working at the same PF.

Comment: The pf and voltage must be equal at the point of coupling. You need to work out what is required internally from that.